# Android: ValueAnimator always gives end value

Tags: android, animation

I have below metod to configure my ValueAnimator for cross fading between two colors. But it doesn't work. It always gives ending color value.

```
Integer colorFrom;
Integer colorTo;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    activity = getActivity();
    context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    colorFrom = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.donut_finished_color);
    colorTo = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.Red);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setColorAnimation();
}

private void setColorAnimation() {
    long passedTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() - currentEarlyDate.getTime();
    colorAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(argbEvaluator, colorFrom, colorTo);
    colorAnimator.setDuration(currentPrayerTimeLength);
    colorAnimator.setInterpolator(null);
    colorAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
    colorAnimator.start();
    colorAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(passedTime);
}

@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
    Integer colorValue = (Integer) colorAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Duration : " + colorAnimator.getDuration());
    Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Current : " + colorAnimator.getCurrentPlayTime());
    Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Color : " + colorValue);
    remainingTimeProgress.setFinishedStrokeColor(colorValue);
    remainingTimeProgress.setUnfinishedStrokeColor(colorValue);
}
```

Timing values seems wright on log but animated color value jumps to end

```
09-02 17:53:22.032    updateLocationNamesList
09-02 17:59:30.104    setColorAnimation - Length : 10620000
09-02 17:59:30.104    setColorAnimation - Passed : 4290093
09-02 17:53:22.099    onAnimationUpdate - Duration : 10620000
09-02 17:53:22.099    onAnimationUpdate - Current : 0
09-02 17:53:22.099    onAnimationUpdate - Color : -16058881
09-02 17:53:22.100    onAnimationUpdate - Duration : 10620000
09-02 17:53:22.100    onAnimationUpdate - Current : 0
09-02 17:53:22.100    onAnimationUpdate - Color : -10183775
09-02 17:53:22.102    onAnimationUpdate - Duration : 10620000
09-02 17:53:22.102    onAnimationUpdate - Current : 2
09-02 17:53:22.102    onAnimationUpdate - Color : -65536 //Quickly jumps to end
```

Can't figure out what is wrong?

Comment: make sure you have Animations enabled in your device "developer options"

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the problem.

Comment: @pskink please put your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

make sure you have Animations enabled in your device `"developer options"`, if disabled your animation simply jumps from `"start"` to `"end"` value

Comment: I was cleaning my qas :)

Comment: geeeez, that wasted so much time from me! I had all animations disabled on my phone for performance reasons and couldn't imagine that it affects `ValueAnimator` and other related classes! Thanks you saved the rest of my day :)

Comment: OMG, lifesaver! And to think I've spend hours trying to figure out why on earth my progress bars weren't showing anymore...